# How do I find out which grid row was clicked for contextmenu?

Tags: android, grid, click, contextmenu, position

I've got a custom layout which is like a grid. I registered it for contextmenu. Now if I do a long click on it, I'd like to know the position where the user clicked on. I have to let my custom layout implement MenuInfo right? But what about the click position?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
                (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

            delete(info.id);
            return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

In `onContextItemSelected()`, if the context menu is for an `AdapterView` (e.g., `GridView`), you can cast the `item.getMenuInfo()` object to an `AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` object. That object has an `id` and a `position` field. The `id` is the `_ID` if you are using a `CursorAdapter`. The `position` is the index into your adapter.

Comment: Thanks... I already knew how to get the id of an AdapterView that way. But my problem is that I have a custom layout which doesn't extend GridView. I think I have to create a MenuInfo on my own in that layout class, but I don't know how to get the click position, I need a row number in a MenuInfo object... :-/

Comment: @cody: Oh, whoops, sorry, I thought you had written that it *was* a `GridView`. "but I don't know how to get the click position" -- either hunt through the `AdapterView` code to see how they do it, or register a context menu for each cell rather than for the grid as a whole.

Comment: Perhaps I'd have to override setOnCreateContextMenuListener() in my class, or something. I need the context menu to create a new child on that position.

Comment: Ok my view doesn't have "cells" it has only childs that have an own contextmenu..

Comment: I can't figure out how to solve that.. do you know how to get the physical position of a click on the screen?

Comment: @cody: Register a context menu for each "childs that have an own contextmenu". In `onCreateContextMenu()`, you will be told what child this is, in the form of the passed-in `View`.